# Used P2V to reduce size of LVM VHDX - Issues with grub and booting now

Tags: grub2, fstab, lvm

Hi All hoping for some Linux genius advice

I inherited a VMWare VM cluster with a few production VM’s

they were all way over provisioned and all have 1tb Thick drives

But are only using 100gb odd each

My Main intention with this project is to reduce the size of the VHDX from 1 tb to something closer to what they are actually using.
Each VM is at times doing 1TB of backup because of the lvm disk

If there is a better way to accomplish this aside from the way i am trying i am open to that

I have used P2V to “move” a test vm on the same host but with a smaller vhdx,

The process went fine until ±97% (which i have read is common)

but now my vm doesn’t boot is says

Error Loading operating system.

Below are screenshots of the blkid and fstab and the grug.cfg of the mounted partitions on the broken VM

I know i need to update fstab with the new uuid’s but i just don’t know which one to use.

Also how do I recreate grub? Can i use something like supergrub2 or do i have to go through grub file and manually change uudi?

All files pulled by Booting into live cd and mnt the partitions

[boot.cfg](https://justpaste.it/9ks66)

[FSTAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToeJi.jpg)

[BLKID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBhop.jpg)

[LVDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg5NP.jpg)

[LVDisplay1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zXt6.jpg)

[PVDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coOka.jpg)

Comment: I get page not found and requests to remove add blocker from your links.

Comment: All my images are hosted in imgur and i have the boot.cfg pasted in justpaste.it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
This solution is only valid for LVM systems

1. complete failed clone
2. boot failed clone to live cd
3. mount file system
4. run in terminal pvdisplay & vgdisplay & lvdisplay & blkid to get the new UUID of your system
5. edit fstab and boot.cfg and replace the current UUID with the new ones you got in the previous step ( i ran the same commands on the old system for cross reference)
6. boot new system with supergrub2 iso this should get you into your "new" VM
7. run sudo grub-install /dev/dsa
8. run sudo update-grub

System should now boot without issue